# rake db:migrate rake aborted! Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'simple_cms'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

[image: Database.yml]

When I run rake db:migrate from my simple_cms/

I get this error.

> rake db:migrate rake aborted! Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user
>   'simple_cms'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Iv'e followed some of the steps outlined in previous questions. I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: You have to create a user with a password ...and then  assign it as owner of your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access denied for user 'simple_cms'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

```
1.) Check login credentials Username and password.
2.) Create another user account to simulate the error.
3.) Use another username and password if necessary.
```